# IIS PUT does not work, but GET and POST work

Tags: asp.net, iis, webapi

I have an IIS WebAPI in ASP .NET 4.8.0.

It works with GET and POST methods. However, when I tried PUT, it returns a 404 - Not Found error.

I resolved the problem by adding this to my Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Now PUT works. However, the problem now is that whenever I use any request for the resource that does not exist in the app, I get 200 OK response, instead of 404 - not found.

Can somebody help me as to what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around a bit and I deleted the handlers tag. So now, my system.webServer tag within Web.config file looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Now PUT works for valid resources, and for invalid resources I get 404 - Not Found, which is what I wanted.
It all works now. However, if somebody could explain to me why this works, I would be very grateful :)